# IIS website (.asmx service app) is only reachable by IP, but not by domain/host name

Tags: iis, asmx, windows-server

I have a Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 installed on it. I have just one website configured which is the default web site. It contains an application which is configured as follows:

- The physical path points to the app directory, where I have a `web.config` and a `Service.asmx` file
- the virtual path of the app is set to `/service`

With this configuration, my app can be loaded via: `127.9.9.9/service/Service.asmx` (let's say `127.9.9.9` is the IP of my windows server here). This works both locally on the Windows server as well as from an outside machine. So far so good.

But now I wanted to make the app accessible via a domain name, because obviously it is a better and more common solution than going via IP. So, I added a binding for my default web site in IIS with a hostname, let's call it `mydomain.com`. I left the other binding settings default, i.e. the binding works on port 80 and with any IP address.

After having configured the binding, the app is now also accessible via `mydomain.com/service/Service.asmx`, *but* only locally on the Windows server machine! When calling this URL from an outside machine, I just get

> site not found

Of course, `mydomain.com` has a redirection to the Windows server, i.e. to IP `127.9.9.9`. And when calling just `mydomain.com`, it successfully redirects to the Windows server, and I get to see the standard IIS welcome screen. However when trying to accessing the app `mydomain.com/service/Service.asmx` it fails.

After having done some research it seems it's a DNS issue. So, following a tutorial, I configured a forward lookup zone, which maps the hostname `mydomain.com` to the IP of the app server. Note that this is not `127.9.9.9`, the app server has a different IP! But as I understood, that's how it is supposed to be configured? Also, I added a reverse lookup zone for that IP. As it still didn't work, I even played around with the network adapter of the Windows server, and added the app server's IP at the top of the list of DNS ip's. But still it doesn't work.

I'm afraid I don't quite understand the DNS part fully. Maybe is there something missing in the configuration of mydomain.com? As I said, I configured a redirection ("MX") from a hostname to the Windows server IP. I don't understand my mydomain.com successfully leads me to the Windows Server start page, but mydomain.com/service/Service.asmx cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should do following configurations to access your site through the domain. This is mainly three step process.

1. Changes at your domain registrar: It is good practice that you register private nameservers at your domain registrar. You will have to assign your app server IP in the nameserver. So assuming that your app server has IPs like 72.11.11.11 and 72.11.11.12, you should register nameservers as below

ns1.mydomain.com - 72.11.11.11
ns2.mydomain.com - 72.11.11.12

Once the nameservers are registered, assign them to mydomain.com

2. Next you have to configure the DNS manager of your app server. You will have to add following DNS records.

Name: @ (or blank)
Type: A
Data: 72.11.11.11

Name: * (a star)
Type: A
Data: 72.11.11.11

Name: www
Type: A
Data: 72.11.11.11

Name: (blank)
Type: NS
Data: ns1.mydomain.com

Name: (blank)
Type: NS
Data: ns2.mydomain.com

These are minimum DNS records which you will have to add. There are many other which you can add like MX, ftp, mail etc based on your requirement.

3. The last action is to be performed in the IIS. Click on the site name mydomain.com in the IIS. In the right side Action pane, click on 'Bindings' under Edit Site section. You should add two bindings.
   Type: http
   IP: 72.11.11.11
   Port: 80
   HostName: mydomain.com

Type: http
IP: 72.11.11.11
Port: 80
HostName: www.mydomain.com

Hope above will help you.

Regards,
C